# Pythonic way to get last index value of enumerate

Tags: python, enumerate

When I enumerate through a list, is there an intended, pythonic way of obtaining the last index value provided?

Something that would get the equivalent of this:

```
highest = None
for index, value in enumerate(long_list):
    # do stuff with index and value
    highest = index
return highest
```

This approach I don't like. It has hundreds of unnecessary variable assignments. Also, it's ugly.

Background: I have an ordered list build with a RDBS and SQLAlchemy, using numbers as indexes in the relation table. Also I store the highest used index number in the list table, for easy appending of new entries (without extra max lookup on relation table). For when things get messed up, for whatever reason, I included a reorg function, that rebuilds indexes starting from 0 (to remove any gaps). I to that by for-enumerate-iterating over the association table. After that I need to count them or max the index, to get my new highest index value for the list table. That kinda bugs me.

Suggestions? Preferably something that works in 2.7.

Comment: the last index? something like `len(long_list) - 1`?

Comment: `long_list[-1]` gets the last element in a list, `len(long_list) - 1` gets the last index in a list

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. But the list behind that is something more complex that acts like a python list, so that might recalculate that value in a more complicated way. Just feels wrong, when I just did that in the loop.

Comment: If you are already iterating over the list before this step, why not store the count then?

Answer (score 5):

To get the last index of a list

```
len(mylist)-1
```

To get the last element of a list you can simply use a negative index.

```
mylist[-1]
```